# Do I need a dedicated graphic card for ubuntu?

Tags: graphics

I want to purchase a new laptop. I looking for HP laptop (15-BS145TU) i5 8th generation 8250 which has integrated graphic card UHD 620. It will have 8 Gb DDR4 ram and 1TB 5400rpm Serial ATA hard drive. 
The other configuration of the laptop (15-bs179TX) will also include 2 GB AMD Radeon 520 Graphic card.

I mostly use laptop for programming in ubuntu like cpp, cern root, Geant, video rendering etc. I don't play game but watch movies. I also do programming in visual python which may use processing for 3D visualization.

It will be helpful it you can suggest, should I go for laptop with dedicated graphic card or without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu is working very well with integrated Intel graphic card. The answer is no, you definitely don't need to choose a laptop with a dedicated graphic card.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Thinkpad T430 that has Intel graphics (built into the CPU) -- Core i5 at 2.9 GHz nominal clock (up to 3.4 GHz turbo), 2 cores/4 threads and 8 GB RAM (some of it shared with graphics).  Before the cooling started to degrade (likely due to dust or pet hair in the passages) I got very good performance, better than my desktop (Core2Quad 2.7 GHz, 8 GB RAM, and GTX750), even with games like There and Kerbal Space Program, as well as YouTube.

Based on my experience, if you're not a heavy duty gamer, you won't find Ubuntu badly handicapped by using integrated graphics as opposed to a dedicated GPU.